# How could the command pattern be replaced by lambda expressions?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

This is kind of a follow-up to another question ([Reuse code for looping through multidimensional-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973457/reuse-code-for-looping-through-multidimensional-array)) where my specific problem was resolved by using the command-pattern. My problem was, that I had multiple methods performing operations on every element of a two-dimensional array - and therefore a lot of duplicate code. Instead of having many methods like so...

```
void method() {
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < foo[i].length; j++) {
            // perform specific actions on foo[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

... I solved it like this:

```
interface Command {
    void execute(int i, int j);
}

void forEach(Command c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < foo[i].length; j++) {
            c.execute(i, j);
        }
    }
}

void method() {
    forEach(new Command() {
        public void execute(int i, int j) {
            // perform specific actions on foo[i][j];
        }
    });
}
```

Now if we had lambda expressions in Java, how could this be shortened? How would that  look like in general? (Sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here simple example with Java 8 lamdas. If you change a bit `Command` class so it will look like this:

```
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface Command {
        void execute(int value);
    }
```

Here it will accept value from sub array. Then you could write something like this:

```
    int[][] array = ... // init array
    Command c = value -> {
         // do some stuff
    };
    Arrays.stream(array).forEach(i -> Arrays.stream(i).forEach(c::execute));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Could you explain what the "Arrays.stream"-method does?

Comment: It just returns [Stream](http://lambdadoc.net/api/index.html?java/util/stream/Stream.html) :) You can [try](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html) yourself.